# Ubuntu 16.04 Server 32bit to change 64bit

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, 32bit-64bit, php-5.6

The server instance was initially created 32bit. After that, it was upgraded to a 64bit. If I go to the terminal and check the command `uname -im`, `uname -a` ( x86_64 )then I see OS 64bits.

If I check with its command `getconf LONG_BIT` then output get `32`.

The problem I have is that when I installed PHP5.6 it only supported 32bits. As a result, PHP is not fully supporting my code. As I am facing issues regarding php **max upload size**. I can't able to upload file max size 2gb because of php 32bit. My problem may be solved if I go to php 64bit. Let me know if you have a better solution.

`$ php -r 'echo PHPINTMAX;'`

`2147483647`

Please give me a solution so I can do my job properly.

Comment: You may have to uninstall the 32bit PHP and re-install the 64bit PHP

Comment: Not sure this question is really a good fit for stack overflow. I t might be better to ask such kind of questions in https://superuser.com/

Apart fromthat it's probably a good idea to switch to 64 bits

Comment: Agree this should be migrated. Perhaps to https://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: Also, jumping off from @aynber 's comment, it sounds like you compiled PHP on the x86 target, and now you're trying to run it on x86_64? If so, have you tried completely uninstalling PHP and reinstalling it compiled for the correct target architecture? Keep in mind that any software you compiled before the upgrade may now have to be recompiled to run properly.